# pycharm importable Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

This question has been asked here: [Pycharm error Django is not importable in this environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363661/pycharm-error-django-is-not-importable-in-this-environment) However my requirement is more specific.

Sadly, our repo has a copy of Django inside it for some long lost legacy versioning requirement which probably originated from the muffled gargles of a previous developer choking on her coffee being mistaken for approval of this idea. Let's say it isn't feasible for `django` to exist anywhere but the `src` folder of this project (for now) ...

How can I get Pycharm to stop complaining about this every time I launch tests or anything else? The 2 seconds to close that dialog are quickly adding up.

Comment: aside: My backup plan is to install vanilla Django in the virtualenv bound to the python interpreter and ensure my local django is first in the python path

Comment: This seems like a good plan to me. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Problem is, as soon as a module present in the installed version which isn't in the "forked" version is imported, it wouldn't be clear. I can't work out at which commit the local version was added to the repo. Even subtle naming differences could cause issues. Seems sketchy/leaky