# Virtualenv django package unresolved

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and find my django package always unresolved, but the project runs successfully, the interpreter setting is right, the pip list shows the django package, I clip some pics here, can someone tell me how to remove these warnings? Are there any pronlems in environment variables or version conflicts?

Warnings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYyZr.png)

Interpreter setting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAbDg.png)

project structure setting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djmfR.png)

run/debug configuration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVDNU.png)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to run it with virtual environment ?  use the [poetry](https://pypi.org/project/poetry/)
to avoid the conflicts with other django projects in your local machine, i am not
sure but the maybe it conflicts with other django project with different version
poetry provides the version control file, this link will help you to configure poetry with django project [poetry Cheatsheet](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/)

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

"Django is not importable in this environment" is probably the decisive error message. The causes for it seem to vary, but many are treated here: [Pycharm error Django is not importable in this environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363661/pycharm-error-django-is-not-importable-in-this-environment)